# Computing $E(XY)$ for finding $Cov(X,Y)$

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider tossing a cubic die once and let $n$ be the smallest number of dots that appear on top. Define two random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that:

- $X=1$ if $n \in \left \{1,2  \right \}$, $X=2$ if $n \in \left \{3,4  \right \}$ and $X=3$ if $n \in \left \{5,6  \right \}$ and
- $Y=0$ if $n \in \left \{3,6  \right \}$, $Y=1$ if $n \in \left \{1,4  \right \}$, and $Y=2$ if $n \in \left \{2,5  \right \}$

Find the $cov(X,Y)$.

The support of $X$ is $\left \{1,2,3  \right \}$ and the support of $Y$ is $\left \{0,1,2  \right \}$.

The marginal probabilities are $f_{x}(X=1)=\frac{1}{3}$, $f_{x}(X=2)=\frac{1}{3}$, and $f_{x}(X=3)=\frac{1}{3}$ and the same for $Y=\left \{ 0,1,2 \right \}$
I have found $E(Y)=\frac{1}{3} (0) + \frac{1}{3} (1) + \frac{1}{3} (2) = 1$ and $E(X)=2$.

The formula for $Cov(X,Y) = E[(X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))]$, so I have $$Cov(X,Y) = E[(X-2)(Y-1)]=E[XY - X - 2Y +2]=E[XY]-E[X]-2E[Y]+2= E[XY] -2-2+2= E[XY] - 2.$$

**EDIT:** I was stuck on the $E[XY]$ part but have an answer now.

Comment: Are you saying you cannot compute E(XY)?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure how.

Comment: The same way you computed $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$. Just write the values of the product $(X-2)(Y-1)$ for different values of $n$ and then take the average.

Comment: For the uniform distribution (not explained in the question), **by definition**, $$E(XY)=\frac16\sum_{n=1}^6X(n)Y(n).$$

Comment: Why downvote? The question is perfectly formatted, and there is a big amount of own progress explained. (Sorry for off-topic.)

Comment: @zhoraster I would have included the joint distribution table but cannot do it in LaTex that well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tabulate:**
$\boxed{\begin{array}{r|r}
n & 1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6 \\ \hline
X & 1& 1& 2& 2& 3& 3 \\ \hline
Y & 1& 2& 0& 1& 2& 0 \\ \hline
(X{-}\mathsf E(X))(Y{-}\mathsf E(Y)) & 0 & -1 & 0 &0 &1 &-1
\end{array}}$

Comment: Yes, but how can I get the expectation of $(X-E(X))(Y-E(Y))?$

Comment: @OGC The same way you obtained the expectations of $X$ and $Y$. Sum the values, then divide by six.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out. The support of $E(XY) = \left \{0,1,2,3,4,6  \right \}$.

So $E(XY) = \frac{1}{3} (0) + \frac{1}{3} (1) +\frac{1}{3} (2) + \frac{1}{3} (3) + 0 + 0 = 2$

So $Cov(X,Y) = 2-2=0$.